# How to pass parameter value to crystal report's data source

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

i got a stored procedure and i got it going in my crystal report

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SP_MainContent]
(       @from int,
        @to int,
        @year int,
        @office varchar(MAX),
        @fund varchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
  SELECT AccntTbl.Id,
         AccntTbl.accnt,
         ISNULL(SupplyTbl.Supply, 0) AS Supply,
         AccntTbl.office,
         AccntTbl.exp,                 
         AccntTbl.dateCreated 
  FROM AccntTbl 
  LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT idAccnt, 
             SUM(amount) AS Supply
     FROM SuppyTbl AS SupplyTbl1
     WHERE MONTH(dateCreated) BETWEEN @from AND @to 
       AND YEAR(dateCreated) = @year 
       AND fund = @fund
     GROUP BY idAccnt) AS SupplyTbl     
  WHERE YEAR(AccntTbl.dateCreated) = @year 
    AND AccntTbl.office = @office 
    AND AccntTbl.fund = @fund 
  GROUP BY AccntTbl.Id,
           AccntTbl.accnt,
           AccntTbl.appro,
           Supply.Supply
);
```

and in VB.NET

```
Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("SP_MainContent '" & 1 & "', '" & 2 & "', '" & 2016 & "', " & _
                             "               'office', 'food'", conn)
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim rpt As New CRreport
ad.Fill(ds, "SP_MainContent")
rpt.SetDataSource(ds)

CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
```

but every time i open up the report this window will pop-up, its is so annoying.

[image]

how to stop this to pop up ? whenever i open up my report in vb.net

glad for any help..tnx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass parameter values like below

```
  rpt.SetParameterValue("@param_name", the_value)
```

Comment: by this..i can get rid of that window to pop-up..sir ?

Comment: @yoyieyoyie Try it on your code first before asking